# Why does my flyback transformer simply refuse to work?

Tags: transistors, transformer, high-voltage, flyback, winding

I've been trying to create a Kirlian setup like the one in a video by 'The Plasma Channel', and the flyback transformer for the power source just refuses to work.

I have a T1010A transformer, and I'm winding its core by hand. I have a IRFZ44N transistor to drive it and for the power source I'm using a battery eliminator at 4 volts. I have tried possibly anything. I've changed the transformer three times, the transistor and resistors (220 ohm) more than ten times and even the power source (which I fried three times.)

Previously I had managed to get 4-6 kV, but now for more than a month I've been trying and nothing.

Is there something I've been doing wrong or something I could change to make it work?

Here is the circuit diagram which I did not make:

[image]

Here is an image of it (which is also not mine since I'm not using batteries but a battery eliminator)

[Image and Diagram taken from a video by Mr. Dhanoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ii3l2Ib27k&t=3s)

[image]

Comment: First, when you driving self-oscillated converter with mosfet always put a 15v zener between G and S. Even small voltage spike above 20V or below 20V can destroy the gate.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, What is a genzer? If you mean a protective sleave then yes, I have been using them at the connection points to prevent sparks

Comment: It’s a diode used as voltage clamp (also).

Comment: Please post a schematic along with transformer specs.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I could try that but still I've changed the transistors more than 10 times and they do show continuity, Which I believe shows that they are working pretty fine

Comment: The next point, using mosfet as it is in schematic you are not able to regulate the oscillations easily what end up in extreme boost effect draining a huge current from battery (charging primary too much and destroing mosfet after few seconds).

Comment: @Newfoundlander That is a FET type of transistor. Depending on which terminal you probed, and which polarity, you may have proved with your measurements that the transistor has burned short. There is not enough info to know if the circuit  you tried has a chance to work or if it is a fake. For some reason, some people like to make videos about random circuits with spark plugs in them and say they generate energy, while actually some motor or lamp is powered by a hidden battery.

Comment: So there is two way how to regulate it: Fine tuning of input voltage (not good idea) or place about 6v8 zener between GS according to mosfet Gate threshold voltage (much better idea.) There is also possible implement a feedback control but it’s a more complex.

Comment: @Justme, nope the Video is not false as I said I was able to get around 4-6kV, but now it just refuses to do anything even after getting new components multiple times, plus every video that I've come across either uses this method or an LED driver

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, Well the Gate threshold voltage seems to be about 4 volts, so I could try that.

Comment: Zener is connected cathode to Gate and anode to Source. Try zeners 5v6, 6v2, 6v8 a find one best fits you. Higher zener voltage -> more primary charging-> more output voltage.

Comment: Btw, I would wind at least 10 turns primary and 10 auxiliary otherwise the frequency goes too high (causing lot of switching losses and frying the transistor). Maybe 15.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Don't more turns make the voltage go down?

Comment: Also I should clarify that the transistors do seem to get hot when I supply them with the power, this might or might not be relevant per se

Comment: Yes, you get lower output voltage with more prim. turns but I doubt the designers in CRT era drove flyback at 1MHz.

Comment: What is a "Kirlian setup"?

Comment: @Hearth:  That's a setup for [Kirlian photography.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirlian_photography)  You use high voltage to expose a photgraphic plate to make pictures of the surface of the object connected to the high voltage.  There's a lot of woo tied up with it.  It does, however, make some really cool looking pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this circuit.](https://www.imagesco.com/kirlian/HVPS.pdf) That's a company that makes and sells power supply kits for Kirlian photography.

[image]

That circuit uses an LM555 as an oscillator.  It then drives the transformer through a rather hefty transistor.

The circuit you are trying to use attempts to use the MOSFET both as the oscillator and the driver.  That can be made to work, but it is extremely fiddly, as you have found.

Proper function of the circuit you have depends on getting the primary coil wound correctly (correct inductance value, correct center tap, neatly wound.) It also depends on the characteristics of the wire, the bobbin, and the MOSFET.  If anything is a bit out of whack, it may sort of work or not work at all.

As noted in the comments, it is also possible for the gate voltage to get out of hand and destroy your MOSFET.  There's nothing to protect the MOSFET at all.  The oscillations from the coil can easily generate voltages that will exceed the maximum gate-source voltage of your MOSFET.

You can use your own flyback transformer with that circuit.  It ought to work.

The circuit I linked to generates AC because it uses a transformer for the output.  Your flyback transformer is actually a flyback module from a television set.  It has a diode (and maybe a voltage tripler) built in.  It will produce DC.

- Use a separate oscillator.
- Use a driver that cannot exceed the gate voltage of your MOSFET.
- Be very careful with that thing.  If it works, it can generate high voltage and enough current to kill you.

---

The circuit in the video you linked to is attractive for its apparent simplicity.  In reality, such circuits are finicky and difficult to get working properly.  It looks like something you can bash together in an evening and then get on with the things you wanted to do with it.

You'll end up spending more time twiddling with the apparently simple circuit (and possibly failing) than you would spend building a more complex looking but more reliable circuit.

You may want to look at [this project on Hackaday.io](https://hackaday.io/project/175773-diy-a-high-voltage-kirlian-photography-device)

It includes this schematic for a flyback driver:

[image]

Leave out the audio jack, and it'll do what you need.