# Do Kirlian setups work with DC power?

Tags: transformer, ac, dc, high-voltage

I have been trying to build a simple Kirlian setup, and I've been trying to make my flyback transformer work, to no avail, so I shifted to use the small black 3.7 V to 400 kV transformers (as they like to advertise.  I reckon they only give about a maximum of 50 kV, but they pack a big punch.)

The transformer seems to work (not the flyback, that's still refusing to work) and output around 30-35 kV, except I just figured out it gives DC HV output. Nevertheless, I hooked it up to the Kirlian setup, and it made a good static electricity generator and a levitator of light magnetic things somehow, but none to very little sparks.

Do these Kirlian setups work with DC HV or do they only work with AC?

I tried to do some reading but some of the articles said that is does work with DC and some said that it doesn't. So does it? If it does, is there anyway to get more or any coronal discharges?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my flyback transformer simply refuse to work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689329/why-does-my-flyback-transformer-simply-refuse-to-work)

Comment: @winny Nope it doesn't for that is a different question I asked

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The previous question as very simply visible asks why my transformer seems to not be working and how I could get it to work with relevant data about it, whereas this question asks if Kirlian setups work with DC HV and if they do is there anything that could be done to increase the coronal discharge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this paper,](https://web.archive.org/web/20220618134455id_/https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/photogrst1964/46/6/46_6_463/_pdf) Kirlian photography will work with DC.

There's mention of some differences between Kirlian pictures made using AC and Kirlian pictures made using DC.

The polarity of the discharge (whether the object or the film is positive) determines which type of certain features are present.  When the object is positively charged and the film is negative, then you get lines radiating from the object (as in the examples in the paper.) When the polarity is inverted, you tend to get dots around the image.

Using DC, you can change the appearance of the image by swapping polarity.  Using AC, you will get a mixture of both types of features.

---

Both the flyback transformer you were trying to use in the other question and the high voltage module you are asking about here produce DC.

The flyback transformer you have is from a television set.  It uses a built in diode to produce DC for the acceleration voltage of the picture tube.  It has to be DC to accelerate the electron beam.  Depending on what kind of TV you took it from, it may have a voltage tripler built in to generate a higher voltage.  Color TVs had a tripler while black and white TVs could use a lower acceleration voltage and didn't need the tripler.